# Cognos Analytics: running difference with null or 0 values

Tags: null, analytics, cognos

I've created a rather basic crosstab with product and productgroup as rows and year with turnover and margin as columns:

```
                       2018              2017               Difference
                       Turnover Margin   Turnover Margin    Turnover Margin
Climbing gear - Rope    10        3        5        1          5       2
              - Jacket  15        5        -        -          -       -
```

I've created a difference column with the running-difference command and it works great except when there are NULL values in the crosstab. This results in no values in the difference column, which makes sense since a running difference with NULL is NULL. But when I create a data item for turnover / margin which has a certain value (0 or 1) when NULL is encountered, the Difference tab still remains empty. I reckon I've put the correct solve orders since the difference tab works fine when there are values present in the other columns. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this? The difference column should be filled even when there is only 1 value for 2018 for example.

Kind regards,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the coalesce function to output 0 when null values are present?

```
coalesce([Data Item],0)
```

..where [Data Item] is the item that could contain nulls. Coalesce returns the first non-null value in a list of values starting with the leftmost item and working to the right.

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for the delayed answer. But I've tried this and 0's are indeed returned but are not calculated in the running-difference.